# Can someone help me figure out why my PC doesn't boot up properly with my ATI 5850 card? (Video link included)

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

When I turn on my pc (cold start) my video card (Gigabyte ATI 5850) makes some weird fan-noises ... like it doesn't have enough power. I have replaced my `Antec 450W` with an Antec 750W TruePower (brand new), but this did not solve it.

I've [made a video of the boot up process](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAECO2Qt7TI). Please have a look/listen.

What is weird, is that if I ignore that boot up error, I can run windows ok.

Can anyone help? Suggestions?

Motherboard is an asus P5N-EM HDMI (if that helps).

Comment: Have you connected the 6-pin PCI-E power connector ?

Comment: yep. if you looked at the video, the card has 2x 6 pin PCI-E connectors and I've shown that in the video and even said that in the vid.

Comment: are they on the same rail?  I remeber when I installed a new gpu it stated that the two pcie 6 connectors had to be from different rails.  just check that they dont connect to the same cable going back to the psu.

Comment: no idea. My psu has two `PCI-Express` plugs .. which i used to plug into the top of the GPU.

Comment: Does the computer post with a different graphics card? Does the graphics card work on a different computer?